# High Density Memory in Hazelcast (Native memory Size Limit)

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am using Hazelcast 3.5.3 and 3.6 enterprise version to implement High Density memory,Which initializing first Pooled Native Memory and then Off Heap memory. WHich is working fine and creating the Native memory, Which I can check in Hazelcast Managment Console.

My Question is : How can we set the upper limit of Native memory so If I will start Two or One instanceof Hazelcast then it will not cross that Upper limit during assignation of Native memory.

I appreciate for your response in advance.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can configure native memory limit by programmatic or decleratively.
See https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-reference-manual/blob/master/src/Storage/ConfiguringHD.md

Note that maximum sizes are Hazelcast instance based, not JVM process (there may be multiple Hazelcast instance in the same JVM process) or not host (there may be multiple Hazelcast instance on the same host)